# Expression for this matrix transformation that assigns replicas of main diagonal as columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am looking for an elegant way to make the following transformation of a matrix:
\begin{equation}
M := \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

to

\begin{equation}
C:= \begin{bmatrix}
a & e & i \\
a & e & i \\
a & e & i \\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

In other words, I am looking for a transformation $f$ that uses matrix multiplication or perhaps more exotic matrices so that I can write $C=f(M)$.

Is that possible? I have made a few attempts of the form $C = A M B$ but none worked so far.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it works almost.

1. Pick single elements
   $$\tag{1}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix} 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   a & b & c \\
   d & e & f \\
   g & h & i \\
   \end{bmatrix} 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix} =
   \begin{bmatrix}
   a & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix} 
   $$
2. Do same to get $\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & e & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & i \\
   \end{bmatrix}$ .
3. Multiply each matrix that has only one element being not zero with a permutation matrix. For example
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
   \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & e & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & e & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$
4. Add up all matrices $\begin{bmatrix}
   a & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & e & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$ etc.

Comment: great! thank you! That way I can keep the original matrix in.